# Django: Wrong permissions for created SOCK file using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, linux, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django app running on my server using Apache2 and mod_wsgi. I also having WSGI running in daemon mode. Due to this, I have a small issue that occurs every time I restart my apache2 service.

A new sock file is created in `/var/run/` which isn't the issue itself, but due to this, the new file is being created by root and given the owner www-data, my user who is serving the files is not the owner.

**My Question**:

How do I make it so that the new sock file being created is created with *user* as the owner and *www-data* as the group?

Comment: Usually the default behaviour is fine and works out of the box. What version of mod_wsgi are you using? What is the actual error message you are seeing in the Apache error log? What MPM are you using in Apache? Are you using an MPM, or other configuration that results in each individual request being handled as a user other than ``www-data`` as using such a configuration means you have to set an extra mod_wsgi directive? This is now common if using a CPanel installation of Apache.

Comment: `[Tue Nov 28 22:36:41.523770 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 2753] (13)Permission denied: [client 174.67.255.196:57646] mod_wsgi (pid=2753): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'user' on '/var/run/wsgi.2747.0.1.sock'.` is the error I get. It is satisfied by just doing a chown 'user'. Once I do that, the issue is solved. But a new file is created each restart, so I must do that every time I restart. I am using VestaCP and the latest version of mod_wsgi as well as VirtualHosts through apache2 @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: What about by other questions? What mod_wsgi version are you using? What Apache MPM are you using? And what is result of running ``ls -las`` on file before and after you change ownership?

Comment: I am using `version 4.3` of `libapache2-mod-wsgi` and my server MPM is `prefork` @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Go look at the documentation on ``socket-user`` option to ``WSGIDaemonProcess``. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html You will need to use a newer Python version to get that option, your version is very old, it is definitely not the latest version. You must be using ``PrivilegesMode`` directive already to cause this.

Comment: `ls -las` output BEFORE change is `0 srwx------  1 www-data    root           0 Nov 28 23:12 wsgi.4251.0.1.sock` and AFTER chown is `0 srwx------  1 user     www-data       0 Nov 28 23:12 wsgi.4251.0.1.sock`. I am reading up on the documentation now

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton , I have added a user and group to my `WSGIDaemonProcess` and looked into `PrivilegesMode` but can't quite seem to figure it out. The sock file is still being created with `www-data` being the owner

Comment: I said to look at the ``socket-user`` option. Not ``user`` and ``group``. You don't need to set ``PrivilegesMode`` as you likely already have it set to ``SECURE`` which is the trigger for this issue. Just add ``socket-user=youruser`` option to ``WSGIDaemonProcess``.

Comment: You can't use mod_wsgi 4.3 though I don't think. That version is too old and doesn't support the ``socket-user`` option. Upgrade by uninstalling your system mod_wsgi package and instead install it using ``pip install`` method. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: The ``socket-user`` option was only added in 4.4.1. The latest version is 4.5.22.

Comment: Ah, I see.. My issue with installing mod_wsgi through pip was that I was constantly receiving the `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-LhKUr6/mod-wsgi/` error so I ended up installing `libapache2-mod-wsgi`. I will update my python version and try to work out that error issue when I get back from class. Thank you lots for the help so far!

Comment: If this is your own system and not shared, may be easier to see if you have ``PrivilegesMode`` directive set to ``SECURE`` and perhaps not set it. If only running mod_wsgi that directive probably isn't needed. VestaCP may not let you do that though depending on how much control you have over it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton , I updated to python 2.7.13 and tried running `pip install mod_wsgi` and received an errno 2 message: `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-BEH0vb/mod-wsgi/`. I am able to run the same command on my MacBook and it works fine, however..

Comment: Seems I was missing `apache2-dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @GrahamDumpleton 's help, I was able to solve this issue.

**Problem**

Using the wrong wsgi install (`libapache2-mod-wsgi`) which caused issues when trying to run `WSGIDaemonMode` inside my apache conf file. I was unable to use the `socket-user=user` option so that I did not receive a `Permission denied` problem when a new sock file was created upon service restart.

**Solution**

For me, I did a fresh install of Debian 8 on my server since I was messing around a lot in my files trying to solve the issue, so I felt this was for the best. Upon a fresh install, using `pip install mod_wsgi` was able to work (*would not work before my fresh install, even after installing python 2.7.13*) -- weird, I know...

Since I had `mod_wsgi` installed properly, I was able to use the `socket-user=user` option to solve my problem.

[Documentation for mod_wsgi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi)